# Autocomplete using data from MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I want to make autocomplete feature using jquery ui when searching data from mysql database....for nw am using data from array, but I dont know. How can I check it from the database? Here is my code.

```
<script>
$(function() {
    var availableTags = [
        "ActionScript",
        "AppleScript",
        "Asp",
        "BASIC",
        "C",
        "C++",
        "Clojure",
        "COBOL",
        "ColdFusion",
        "Erlang",
        "Fortran",
        "Groovy",
        "Haskell",
        "Java",
        "JavaScript",
        "Lisp",
        "Perl",
        "PHP",
        "Python",
        "Ruby",
        "Scala",
        "Scheme"
    ];

    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: result_array 
    });
});
</script>
```

any help?

Edit to:

```
?php  
$q=mysql_query("select rfname from research_details") or die(mysql_error()); 

$array_data = mysql_fetch_array($q);

foreach($array_data as $data) {
 $data1[] = "'".$data."',";
}
$data1 = implode(",",$data1); 
$data = substr($data1,0,-1);


?>
$(function() {

var availableTags = [
<?php echo $data; ?>
];
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
source:availableTags 
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can code it like the following:

```
$("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: '/autocomplete_query.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                response(data);
            }
    });
});
```

The structure of the result in your SELECT query at autocomplete_query.php should be something similar to this array:

```
$result = array(0 => "ActionScript", 1 => "AppleScript", 2 => "Asp",...);
```

And then should be returned like this:

```
echo json_encode($result);
```

- And make sure that that's the only `echo` statement on autocomplete_query.php.

Comment: tanx, this seems helpfull....but i don get wat u meant by this **$result = array(0 => "ActionScript", 1 => "AppleScript", 2 => "Asp",...);**

Comment: sorry for that! what i only meant by that was, the `$result` should just be a one-dimensional array and should not be multi.

Answer (score 1):

Using AJAX ([jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)) you can send a request to a PHP file on your server to retrive the data from the database and return it as a [JSON](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) encoded string which you'll then [parse](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) in jQuery / Javascript and add it to the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

In place of availableTags you need to get the result as json format and you can get those results using ajax.On the ajax call you need to get the data from Database and then encode them in JSON format like

```
echo json_encode($result_array);
```

and parse them and add that to the availableTags.Try these [**JSON ENCODE**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Answer (score 0):

Look at the jQueryUI API documentation for [`autocomplete`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source).

Basically, you specify a URL as the `source`. That URL then outputs a page that jQuery can handle, such as JSON or XML data.

```
$('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
    source: '/data/my-page.php'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this. Get data from db as array, then pass it in you jquery function.

```
<?php
$array_data;  // get data from db as array
foreach($array_data as $data) {
$data1[] = "'".$data."',";
} 
$data1=implode(",",$data1);
   $data = substr($data1,0,-1);
?>

<script>
$(function() {

var availableTags = [
<?php echo $data; ?>
];
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
source:result_array 
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: see my update, but i still get a warning  ) Warning: substr() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in

Comment: try with implode function before the substr finction

Answer (score 0):

You need to study following links
  [Link1](http://www.jqueryautocomplete.com/jquery-autocomplete-php-mysql-json-example.html)
  [Link2](http://www.htmlblog.us/jquery-autocomplete)
  [Link3](http://www.daveismyname.com/tutorials/php-tutorials/autocomplete-with-php-mysql-and-jquery-ui/)
and [Demo](http://daveismyname.com/demos/autocomplete/)

Comment: hey thenx alot maryam for dat links, they are great