# Why this form won't call the JS function? (trying to get an autocomplete form field calling a MySQL database with a PHP script and AJAX)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to use the [.autocomplete() function of jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) with a list of usernames taken from a MySQL database (using a PHP script), but for some reason is not working. The console won't show me any errors.

The form have several items in it and it does work ok (the form is at the `editarPerfil.php` file, which gets processed by `guardarConfigPerfil.php` file).

But for some reason, I don't get anything from the JS file, which should be called when the content of the `userName` field is changed.

### This is my HTML form:

```
<form method="POST" action ="guardarConfigPerfil.php">
<div class="form-group ui-widget">
<label for="userName">Username</label>
<input type="userName" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $userName; ?>" name="userName" id="userName" onchange="autocompletarUserNames();">
</div>
```

### This is at my footer on that page:

```
<!-- jQuery y Bootstrap minificados -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/formularios.js"></script>
```

### This is my formularios.js file:

```
function autocompletarUserNames() {
    $( "#userName" ).autocomplete({
                      source: '/perfil/autocompletarUsername.php'
                      });
};
```

### This is my php file:

```
<?php
session_start(); 
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/private/conectar.php';

$conectar = new PDO('mysql:host='.HOST.'; dbname='.DATABASE.'; charset=utf8', USER, PASS); 

    //get search term
    $user = $_GET['userName'];

    $buscarUsuario = $conectar->prepare("
                SELECT userName 
                FROM usuarios 
                WHERE userName 
                LIKE '%?%'
                ORDER BY userName ASC
                ");
    $buscarUsuario->bindParam(1, $user);
    $buscarUsuario->execute();
    $row = $buscarUsuario->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
        $data[] = $value['userName'];
    }

    //return json data
    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Now, when I get into the form, and I click on the userName field and type... nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

The folder tree is set up like this:

```
public_html/perfil/autocompletarUsername.php     <--- the php script
public_html/perfil/editarPefil.php               <--- the form
public_html/js/formularios.js                    <--- the js file
```

Comment: Surround your jQuery with a `$(document).ready()` handler. And why use an inline JS command when you're already using jQuery?

Comment: Thanks! But I'm just trying that and nothing happens. The console is silent as well.

`$(document).ready(
function autocompletarUserNames() {
    $( "#userName" ).autocomplete({
                      source: '/perfil/autocompletarUsername.php'
                      });
});`

Comment: Script is in the footer, wrapping with `$( document ).ready()` isn't required.

Comment: I have seen some issues with that @hungerstar, but you're right. YMMV

Comment: @Jay Blanchard why I'm not sending anything to the function? Shouldn't that ake it from " source: '/perfil/autocompletarUsername.php' " ? I'm sorry for such a silly question, I'm new to JS.

Comment: I misspoke. Because of the way you're using autocomplete it is as if you're not sending anything for the autocomplete function to compare to because of the inline JS call to the function. Are you doing this on a webserver? A request to a server-side script requires that you do this on a webserver.

Comment: @JayBlanchard, could you expand on that? I've never had an issue as long as my scripts are the last tags before the closing body tag. The main point of `$( document ).ready()` is to prevent code from working on a DOM ( or parts of) that might not exist yet. It also provides a level of _portability_. If code is wrapped in `$( document ).ready()` you can place your code in the `<head>`, beginning of page, middle of page etc. and execution will be deferred.

Comment: Anecdotally I have see several setups with jQuery where this has been a problem @hungerstar and there has been many a time (I know intimately what the function is meant for) where suggesting the wrapper function cleared up problems. While a problem has never been precisely pinpointed I have seen where malformed markup (especially prior to HTML5) lead to the issue.

Comment: @Rosamunda have you verified that an Ajax request is being made and if so, that the response contains the data you expect? You can do this with Developer Tools built into the browser (I prefer Chrome) or you can add the following to the config object of autocomplete to verify the response to the autocomplete widget: `{ source: '...', response: function ( event, data ) { console.log( 'autocomplete data', data ); } `.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only ever have to call once:

```
$( "#userName" ).autocomplete({
    source: '/perfil/autocompletarUsername.php'
});
```

Most likely on page load, in the $(document).ready();

It looks like when you make a change to the text box, autocomplete is initiated again and again. Try removing the onChange and calling autocomplete like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#userName" ).autocomplete({
        source: '/perfil/autocompletarUsername.php'
     });
});
```

Once. This is assuming your file path is correct, of course.

Comment: Is your query failing? It looked like you were querying with the contents of the textbox. You don't need to do that. Just remove the where clause in the query.

Comment: Actually, you might be having problems because PHP is server-side and JS is client-side. You'll need to perform an Ajax request to get the data.

Comment: Here's a good example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17213875/autocomplete-using-data-from-mysql

Comment: @MarkBowman [autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) is a jQuery UI widget that performs AJAX.

Comment: @hungerstar you are correct. I was unaware that autocomplete performed Ajax. Thanks. I have only used autocomplete on client-side.